# How to setup geary with IMAP and SSL/TLS encription?

Tags: geary

I tried IMAP setting as pop3 with port 110 with my email id and password and both starttls and as encryption ssl/tls but it says IMAP setting not valid. Similarly, I put SMTP with port 25 with same settings above.

I got an error which says `unable to validate: imap connection error and smtp connection error.` but the surprising thing is the same setting above worked on thunderbird.

Comment: What has this to do with Ubuntu? This sounds like the mail server doesn't support SSL/TLS and STARTTLS.

Comment: @Alvar It's about using software in Ubuntu, so on-topic most likely (depends on the exact cause of the problem, but it should be fine)

Comment: Geary doesn't currently support POP3, only IMAP.  Make sure you're pointing it to an IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the server supports SSL/TLS encryption and that you are using the **correct port**. I'm sure that ports 110/25 are not the correct ones. The following should work:

- IMAP settings:

  - Server: imap.yourdomain.com
  - Port: 993 (this is the standard, you must consult your network administrator)
  - Username: youremail@address (it can be also just `youremail`)
- SMTP settings:

  - Server: smtp.yourdomain.com
  - Port: 465 (this is the standard, you must consult your network administrator)
  - Username: youremail@address (it can be also just `youremail`)